# Call contract methods with web3 from newly created account

Tags: web3js, infura

I need to call methods from my contract in Ethereum without using MetaMask. I use Infura API and try to call my methods from account, recently created with web3.eth.create() method. This method returns object like this:

```
{
    address: "0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cG5834Hfn7d",
    privateKey: "0x348ce564d427a3311b6536bbcff9390d69395b06ed6",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}
```

I also using infura provider:

```
 const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    "https://rinkeby.infura.io/5555666777888"
  ))
```

So, when I try to write smth like that:

```
contract.methods.contribute().send({
          from: '0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cG5834Hfn7d', // here I paste recently created address
          value: web3.utils.toWei("0.5", "ether")
        });
```

I have this error:

> Error: No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor
>   the default options.

How it could be no from address if I write it in from option??

P.S. With Metamask my application works fine. But when I logout from MetaMask and try to create new account with web3.eth.create() method and use it, I have that issue.

Comment: Did you verify that when you re-login in Metamask you had selected Rinkeby testnet and you have a positive balance on that account?

Comment: Well, I don't care of MetaMask actually) I have problem with account that created with `web3.eth.create()` method

Comment: Created it on rinkeby instead of ethereum main blockchain?

Comment: I don't know where this create() method creates account, rinkeby or main network

Comment: Look, there is no problem with MetaMask, there's problem with recently created account from `web3.eth.create()`

Comment: web.eth.create() is a method used to create an account, I know that doesn't have anything involved with Metamask. I'm asking to you if this command you used to create an account was used on rinkeby chain. You can not call a contract function with an ethereum main chain account if the contract is deployed on rinkeby.

Comment: So the only solution is to deploy my contract to main network?

Comment: The expensive one, the cheapest option is to create an account on Rinkeby by using the same method(web3.eth.create()) but on the Rinkeby chain, not with the main Ethereum blockchain geth.

Comment: The thing is I don't know how to create account in rinkeby, according to docs this method creates only in the main network

Comment: I need to create accounts for my users only with web3 library

Comment: https://gist.github.com/cryptogoth/10a98e8078cfd69f7ca892ddbdcf26bc

Here you have it all

Answer (score 1):

I've already faced this problem. You specifying address on `from` field in checksumed format (mixed case). Try to convert it to lowercase and test again. I found it when researched the same issue - looks like `web3` still operated un-checksumed addresses.

Comment: @AlexJohnson maybe you can share minimal reproducible example for your case? Then I can trace it.

Comment: Actually, according to docs, I need to sign transaction with my key, I can't just put recently created account address and call some methods. Now I try to use `ethereumjs-tx` library for doing this

Answer (score -1):

Try setting it up this way:

```
yourContract.options.from = '0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cG5834Hfn7d';
```